# can you limit what an employer can disclose about you

Tags: california, labor-law

I want to list a former employer in California that I resigned from as work experience on my resume but I will not include anyone from that company as a reference.  I do not want anyone from that company disclosing anything about me besides start and end date.  Is there anything I can send this former employer's HR department to limit what they disclose about me?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can ask nicely, but there is nothing you can do legally to prevent your former employer from making disclosures related to your former employment so long as they are true.

Answer (score 1):

[California Labor Code Section 1198.5](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=LAB&sectionNum=1198.5) provides former employees the right to receive a copy of the personnel files and records that relate to the employee's performance or to any grievance concerning the employee.

You may send a formal notice requesting for a copy of your file. In the same letter, you may  request the HR for the company's policy on what information the firm discloses about former employees employment history should a third party inquire. You should definitely receive a response which may alleviate your concern of disclosures or assist you in developing a strategy to reduce adverse exposure.